# Wave Equation (Purpose of $c$)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, waves, acoustics

Consider the sound wave equation: $\dfrac{\partial^2 p}{\partial x^2} = \dfrac{1}{c^2}\dfrac{\partial^2 p}{\partial t^2}$.

Imagine air molecules vibrating. The equation describes the behaviour of particles in the $x$ and $t$ coordinates. But air particles don't vibrate at the speed of sound. So why does speed of sound $c$ appear in the equation?

I know that 'information' travels down the wave at the speed of sound $c$. But I just feel like that is a physical property of the wave. How does an abstract equation relating behaviour of particles in $x$ and $t$ direction know about how fast information travels down the wave?

Comment: The speed of a wave emerging from properties of the things it's composed of is pretty typical. Consider the speed of light emerging from the permittivity and permeability of electric and magnetic fields studied separately. Of course the waves properties come from the thing the waves composed of. you might consider a stretched slinky as a spring and put a wave down it, the properties of the slinky then determine the wave behavior. sorry just time for this comment right now.

Comment: You're talking about sound waves but you've listed this as a question in Electromagnetism. Baffling.

Comment: @MoziburUllah I was studying electromagnetic waves but I found it easier to ask what I was thinking about in terms of sound waves. But the equations are the same right?

Comment: @R.Rankin for sound waves, I can at least picture information travelling down the wave. But for electromagnetic waves, I just don't get why electromagnetic waves originates in the first place

Comment: @confused: Physics is not just about equations but also the physical phenomena that they're embodying ... it's confusing to think otherwise.

Comment: This equation doesn’t describe the individual particles. It describes the sound wave.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is to give the right units. More deeply you should look at the solutions to this equation. These solutions can always be factored as
$$ p(x,t) = R(x-ct) + L(x+ct)$$
For see this you can look at [d'Alambert's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_equation#General_solution), but the fundamental reason is that the wave equation in one-dimension is factored as
$$ \frac{\partial^2 p}{\partial x^2} - \frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial^2p}{\partial t^2} = \left[  \frac{\partial}{\partial x} - \frac{1}{c}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\right]\left[  \frac{\partial}{\partial x} + \frac{1}{c}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\right] p(x,t) = 0 \; . $$

---

#### Velocity of waves

The $R$ and $L$ are functions of only one variable. Thus it has only one "shape" for all times. For example, thought $R$ as having a sharp pike in the origin, thus $R(x-ct)$ will have a pike at the position and time such that $x-ct=0$, i.e. at the position $x=ct$. This means that the wave has moved the distance $ct$ in the time $t$ and it gives the common meaning that $c$ is the velocity of the wave.

Note that the $L$ is a wave that moves with the same velocity $c$ but in the opposite direction. $R$ is sometimes called a wave that propagates to the right and $L$ to the left. When you sum the two partial waves this fixed shape is somewhat lost for general solutions and indeed they don't need to propagate with velocity $c$, they can even be standing wave solutions.

Answer (score 2):

From the dimensionality considerations, a coefficient with dimensions of speed is necessary, since one derivative is in respect to position and the other is in respect to time:
$$
[\frac{\partial^2 p}{\partial x^2}]=\frac{[p]}{L^2}, [\frac{\partial^2 p}{\partial t^2}]=\frac{[p]}{T^2}, [c]=\frac{L}{T}.
$$

One could then ask a more precise question: *why is this coefficient exactly the speed of sound?* The reason is that this equation defines the speed of sound! Indeed, the traditional relation $\omega=ck$ (or $c=\lambda f$) trivially follows from solving the wave equation in terms of plane waves.

Comment: What dimension is [p]?

Comment: It depends on what quantity it is. In this case it is probably pressure, but there are wave equations for all kinds of quantities.